# i don't get the right answer, why?

Tags: java

I'm quite new to java, and I've just started the course for a few days. I wrote the following code to make a simple phone book. It gets names and phone numbers first, then it gets a name and passes the phone number. Except the first name, if I enter any name it will print the last line (the name is not in the list) then the related number!!! Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyPhoneBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] name = new String[200];
        String[] number = new String[200];
        System.out.println("when finished all contacts, just type : finish");
        for (int a = 0; a < 200; a++) {
            System.out.print("\nenter name:");
            name[a] = myScan.nextLine();
            if (name[a].equals("finish")) {
                break;
            } else {
            }
            System.out.print("enter number:");
            number[a] = myScan.nextLine();
        }
        for (int a = 1; a > 0; a++) {
            System.out.println("\nenter name to find number:\n");
            String name2 = myScan.nextLine();
            for (int b = 0; b < 200; b++) {
                if (name2.equals(name[b])) {
                    System.out.println("number is " + number[b]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("----THE NAME IS NOT IN THE LIST----\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: you are storing the word finish as a name in your phonebook. The user can try to search for the name finish which will print *number is null*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a flag for when you find a name that matches user's input and dont print out last line when you find match, for that you could change your code like this:

```
for (int a = 1; a > 0; a++) {
    System.out.println("\nenter name to find number:\n");
    String name2 = myScan.nextLine();
    boolean isNameFound = false;
    for (int b = 0; b < 200; b++) {
        if (name2.equals(name[b])) {
            System.out.println("number is " + number[b]);
            isNameFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isNameFound)
        System.out.println("----THE NAME IS NOT IN THE LIST----\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a map will simplify this
Map<> contactBook = new Hashmap<>()
//then load the map using the phone number and name
You can also use data structure which will not allow dup names